# Can a BufferedReader be sorted?

Tags: java, excel, sorting, bufferedreader

I have an excel file with a list of over 5000 double values, which I read in as a BufferedReader in java eclipse. I want to use this BufferedReader later on, but for this, I need the values of the file to be sorted. Of course, I can just sort the values in excel, but I want to know if it is possible in eclipse too.

I tried to create a String array and sort this, but I don't get how to turn it back into a BufferedReader, since StringReader only allows to have one string read at a time.

I'm just a starter in programming, so if there is a quite easy solution, I would prefer it...

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to turn it back into a BufferedReader? Note that a BufferedReader is just a **reader**, it doesn't write back to the file (so you'd mostly only want to turn it back into a BufferedReader if there's a method you can't change which takes a BufferedReader).

Answer (score 0):

Insert it to the `List` of `Doubles`, then you can perform bubble sort for example.

Comment: It sounds like they already have the reading and sorting figured out, but now need to put their data somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can costruct a BufferedReader from a StringReader

```
BufferedReader buffr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(a_string));
```

But if you sort the string with a list you have to merge the array into a single big string before, with something like:

```
String a_string = String.join("\n", array_of_strings);
```

PS:

It doesn't seem a good idea to use a big string to store numbers. It's a waste of memory... it's not the question though.